# Twig in jquery not able to read jquery variable

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

I am trying to use jQuery post but having issue with the path part where I am using a twig syntax.  Here is the code:

```
messageSender.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var threadId     = $(this).find('a').data('id');

            $.post("{{ path('messages_view', {id: "+threadId+"}) }}", function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
```

This doesn't get the value of the `threadId`, instead it stores the literal ""+'threadId'+"" to the id variable in path.

Comment: Twig isn't able to read `threadId` (a client side value) to make the route. You have to retrieve the route without the parameter then use JS or jQuery to "inject" the threadId value into the route, or use FOSJsRoutingBundle to help you doing that.

Comment: Thanks for that info @Veve, I wasn't aware of the FOSJsRoutingBundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function is in client side (js) 
and your path is in server side (twig)

So that can't work.

To solve this, you can use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle) ([doc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html)).

With your code, you can have something like that:

```
messageSender.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var threadId     = $(this).find('a').data('id');
    var url = Routing.generate('messages_view', { id: threadId});

    $.post(url, function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you are requesting at server run time (twig) something that will be available only at client run time (JavaScript).

To solve, you could set in twig the "data-path" attribute for each `a` tag, and generate the route instead of the "data-id" attribute.
Then, in JavaScript you can just use the entire path, previously generated.