# How to mix twig with javascript variable as a result of Ajax request in success part?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

In my Ajax I'm receiving data:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: Routing.generate('index', {page}),
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.data[0].isbn);// print expecting value well
        $('#foo').append("<a href=\"{{ path('foo', { 'id': data.data[0].isbn }) }}\">");
       //Exception: Variable "data" does not exist
```

This script located in twig file cause:

> Exception: Variable "data" does not exist

How to prepare append() content that contains twig and javascript variable?

Comment: More appropriate duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537752/twig-in-jquery-not-able-to-read-jquery-variable

Comment: check [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html)

Comment: @Veve thanks, so properly I should prepare entire html in controller/template and receive it in Ajax, but what then controller should return, new Response? ahh never mind...

Comment: @Matteo I will, thanks.